# PHP use socks5 proxy with fsockopen ssl

Tags: php, curl, ssl, proxy, socks

I'm trying to open a HTTPs page using php through a socks5 proxy, but I can't use curl, because I have to be able to read each line of the response.

To do that, I'm using this PHP class: http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/socksed/socksed.php, but if I start a connection on port 443, and send a HTTP POST request with params, nginx sends me back this message:

```
400 the plain http request was sent to https port
```

I tried to change that part of the code @fsockopen("tcp:// to @fsockopen("ssl://, but then I can't open the page.

Comment: You can connect to a SOCKS5 proxy using curl by setting the `CURLOPT_PROXY` property. What limitation are you experience with curl that prevents you reading the response?

Comment: I want to read line by line os the response of a download, and drop the connection at a specific point, I don't want to download the whole file in order to find what I want

Comment: You can achieve this with curl's `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` options. I'll post an answer tomorrow if the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using curl, the following should help achieve what you're after:

```
// create the curl buffered reader object with a connection to a socks5 proxy on localhost port 8888
$cbr = new \CurlBufferedReader(array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'socks5://127.0.0.1:8888',
    // disable ssl certificate verification, you probably don't need this so I've commented it out
    //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));

// gets the body at the url up until the point specified by the callback function
$body = $cbr->get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249029/php-use-socks5-proxy-with-fsockopen-ssl',
    /**
     * The callback function to determine whether to continue reading the body sent by the remote server
     * @param string $body
     */
    function (&$body) {
        if (($off = strpos($body, "\nTo do that,")) !== false) {
            // truncate body so that we have everything up until the newline before the string "To do that,"
            $body = substr($body, 0, $off + 1);
        }

        return $off === false; // continue reading while true
    });

echo $body;
```

And the related class:

```
class CurlBufferedReader {
    private $body = false;
    private $callback;
    private $ch;

    public function __construct(array $curlopts = array()) {
        $this->ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($this->ch, $curlopts + array(
            // general curl options
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT   => 30,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION   => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS        => 10,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER   => true,

            // specific options to abort the connection early
            CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE       => 8192,
            CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION    => array($this, 'writeFunction')
        ));
    }

    public function get($url, $callback = null) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $this->callback = $callback;

        if (!($success = $this->exec())) {
            // errno 23 when aborted by the client
            if ($this->getErrno() !== 23) {
                $this->body = false;
            }
        }

        return $this->body;
    }

    public function getBody() {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function getError() {
        return curl_error($this->ch);
    }

    public function getErrno() {
        return curl_errno($this->ch);
    }

    private function exec() {
        $status = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $this->callback = null;
        return $status;
    }

    private function writeFunction($ch, $buffer) {
        $this->body .= $buffer;

        if ($this->callback && !call_user_func_array($this->callback, array(&$this->body))) {
            $written = -1; // user callback requested abort
        } else {
            $written = strlen($buffer);
        }

        return $written;
    }
}
```

It works by reading 8,192 bytes at a time from the remote server. A user function is called to read the total body received upon each read event. The user function must `return false` when it wishes to abort the connection. It's also important to note that `$body` is a reference. Therefore any changes you make to it will affect the string received by the `CurlBufferedReader::get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```